# Can the "escape" trajectory of a gazelle be considered random?

Tags: random-walk, random, biology

I was watching a video of a gazelle escaping from a cheetah and I wondered: may it's trajectory be considered random? Logically speaking, escaping in a random fashion would make almost impossible for the cheetah to predict the the next move, hence increasing chances of survival.

Do you know of any research about this? Do you think their trajectories may resembles something like a Levi flight? Also, if it's objectivelly not random, does it mean it could be predicted? How? I read the "winrate" of a cheetah is as low as 30%, if it was random wouldn't it be 50%?
Gazellle is just an example of course, this may apply to every prey animal that in order to survive has to deal with outrunning the predator.

I know this may not be the correct place to ask but I don't know where this question would fit better. Thank's.

Comment: A gazelle has a finite mass, which means its trajectory has a continuous first derivative, and its second derivative is bounded, so its motion is not a Levy flight. Also note you are confusing notions of random process (ie the trajectory), random outcome (the victor), and equal probability (50%), which need not be simply related.

Comment: In straight line the leopard catches the gazelle because the increment of position (the length of the jump) is larger for cheetah than for gazelle. Therefore exactly after the last jump, if the gazelle changes direction the cheetah will find itself on a correction path requiring a restart in a new straight line, from a speed that prevents the large jumps. So cheetah will accelerate back to intercept speed in a few steps. The break in speed between corrections is enough to make the cheetah abandon the chase.

Comment: Thank's both... I get what you're saying but still the question remain: can the movement of a gazelle be considered random?